# What type of wooden joint to use connecting three wooden beams

Tags: joinery

I'm making a wooden frame (for a loft) and would like to make that without using any angles or fittings.

```
     /-------------
    / |           /|
   ?-------------/ |
   |  |__________|_|
   | /           | /
   |/____________|/
```

I'm looking for joint alternatives for connecting the **corners** without using any metal angles/fittings.

--

Perhaps using a combination of rabbet joint and some other type of joint?

Comment: When it comes to woodworking, would you classify your skills as novice, intermediate, or advanced? Are you looking for simple, easy, or attractive?

Comment: I'm probably novice although I sometimes feel like an intermediate ;) And I'm looking for any alternatives that would look good and at the same time not too complicated. I also should mention I want the box to be near roof height, so preferably no need for screws entering from the top.

Comment: That answer does not seem to include corners, which is what my question is about

Comment: I would suggest migrating this to the Woodworking SE.

Comment: Sounds fitting, please do

Comment: If your vertical posts are 4x4, then you can just butt your horizontal 2x4 members against the 4x4 posts and connect with bolts, screws, or nails.

Comment: This is a good start but the question is currently too broad since there are many ways to join 3 beams at a corner. Do you need the joints to be flush or are you just looking for the simplest way to build a cube? What sizes are your vertical and horizontal members? Do you want to be able to disassemble and reassemble it easily? Is it ok to use metal fasteners or concealed hardware? Is this for a bed? How much weight will it support? Also, this is outside the scope of the question but you should consider adding diagonal cross members to reinforce against racking.

Comment: @andersand sorry for the trouble; please try again to edit the question.

Comment: Hey @andersand, sorry for the trouble. The post should be unlocked, open, and ready to edit now. Flag again if you have any problems

Comment: What are your frame dimensions, and what size lumber have you selected?

Comment: I added an answer to the question here: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/2475/1188